# how can i keep image size in tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, tableview, sdwebimage

This is what I get when I launch my app

[image]

after I click on the cell the images get bigger

[image]

My Code is like this

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)


    // Configure the cell...
    cell.imageView?.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: imageArray[indexPath.row]), placeholderImage:UIImage(named: "pin.png"))

  cell.imageView?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)
    return cell
}
```

imageArray is just string of image URLs. Please help

thanks in advance

Comment: Try setting masks to bounds to imageview and Aspect fill the image

Comment: `cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true;` try this

Comment: Also try replacing your cell with this  --  let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)as UITableViewCell

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work

Comment: Try this `cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the contant mode property:

```
imageViewObject.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
```

or

```
imageViewObject.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
```

or

```
imageViewObject.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the frame in the completion closure of sd_setImageWithURL

```
cell.imageView?.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: "Your URL")!, placeholderImage: nil) { (image, error, cache, url) in
    cell.imageView?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Then i would recommend that you create your own custom cell and set its constraints on your own. You can refer this tutorial if you like http://www.apptuitions.com/uitableview-with-custom-cell-in-swift/

Answer (score 0):

**Take view** that must be greater size then original image view now give ***backgruond color*** to view and **inside that view provide image view**. It may look like fix size of image but having background.